# Next JS Chakra UI problem when trying to extend theme

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, chakra-ui

I'm trying to extend the chakra ui theme but i get this error.

error - Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {semanticTokens, direction, breakpoints, zIndices, radii, blur, colors, letterSpacings, lineHeights, fontWeights, fonts, fontSizes, sizes, shadows, space, borders, transition, components, styles, config}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

Here is my code.

```
import { extendTheme } from '@chakra-ui/react'
import { mode } from '@chakra-ui/theme-tools'

const styles = {
  global: props => ({
    body: {
      bg: mode('#f0e7db', '#202023')(props)
    }
  })
}

const components = {
  Heading: {
    variants: {
      'section-title': {
        textDecoration: 'underline',
        fontSize: 20,
        textUnderlineOffset: 6,
        textDecorationColor: '#525252',
        textDecorationThickness: 4,
        marginTop: 3,
        marginBottom: 4
      }
    }
  },
  Link: {
    baseStyle: props => ({
      color: mode('#3d7aed', '#ff63c3')(props),
      textUnderlineOffset: 3
    })
  }
}

const fonts = {
  heading: "'M PLUS Rounded 1c'"
}

const colors = {
  grassTeal: '#88ccca'
}

const config = {
  initialColorMode: 'dark',
  useSystemColorMode: true
}

const theme = extendTheme({ config, styles, components, fonts, colors })
export default theme
```

Comment: maybe this `"'M PLUS Rounded 1c'"` should have only double quotes but you have added both single and double

Comment: The code you provided doesn't seem related to the error you're seeing. The error complains about an object being rendered in a React component. Could you provide the full stack trace and/or the relevant code?